# How to securely pass data from php forms to html

Tags: javascript, php, html, security, encryption

I have a login system which is an html form and I need to send the username and password back to the php backend where I can there securely encrypt it and store it in a database. I was wondering what the most up to date and secure method of doing this is. Bearing in mind that this is the barebones string form of the password it is very important to be vigilant of the most secure way of passing it back. I know that $_GET and $_POST are extremely unsecure. Do I encrypt the data in javascript before it is sent back to the server hence the javascript hashing algorithm being laid bare to the end user or is simply https encryption sufficient? If I have https encryption would I then simply pass it back using $_GET and $_POST? Thanks

Comment: Yes HTTPS w/ TLS is what to use for securely transmitting data. Hash passwords don't encrypt them.

Comment: [Don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)  and [use the proper methods to hash passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

Comment: Well for sure not in a `GET`, unless you want it in the URL. Just reading your subject it seems you have answered your own question. in order to send data securely between the server and client you need SSL/TLS. I guess you need to ask your self who you are protecting the data from (1st or 3rd party).

Comment: im protecting the data from a third party but I was unsure whether SSL is sufficient. I personally want to protect from both 1st and 3rd party. I am looking to hire people in the future and I need to protect myself from rogue employees as much as possible

Comment: thank you for the responses all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Google for and read relevant information such as [this](https://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).
- Do not hash on the client. Pass the clear-text password to the server.
- Use POST to keep the password out of the URL (URLs have a nasty way of getting logged and otherwise exposed to people).
- I personally recommend to use HTTPS everywhere but the minimum is to use HTTPS for the login form and all pages that follow login.
- Store the password in the database using PHP's `password_hash` function and verify it using `password_verify`.

Comment: Thank you. I was hesitant to go by information on the internet because it may not be current to address the current state of security

Comment: I googled around and found some stale data that recommended using salted hashes instead of key extension functions like what `password_hash` uses. But I think that with the pointers I've given you should be able to find the right material.